# Enabling OpenGL 4.1 under OS X 10.10 with GLEW, GLFW and g++ compilation

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, g++, glfw

I have a 2014 RMBP, updated to the latest version of OS X which should guarantee me compatibility up to OpenGL 4.1. I have put together a minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "GL/glew.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int windowWidth = 800;
    int windowHeight = 800;
    string windowTitle = "title";

    glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);

    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW.\n";
        return 1;
    } else {
        clog << "Initialized GLFW." << endl;
    }

    GLFWwindow* pWindow = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, windowTitle.c_str(), 0, NULL);

    glfwSetWindowPos(pWindow, 700, 200);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(pWindow);
    if( pWindow == NULL )
    {
        cerr << "Failed to open GLFW window.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "GL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << "\n";
    std::cout << "GLSL Version: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Vendor: " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Renderer: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(pWindow))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(pWindow);
    return 0;
}
```

This opens up a window which works fine, but it's outputting the following: 
GL Version: 2.1 INTEL-10.0.86 
GLSL Version: 1.20
Vendor: Intel Inc.
Renderer: Intel Iris OpenGL Engine

which is wrong! I should be getting 4.1 compatibility. I downloaded the examples at https://github.com/tomdalling/opengl-series and under xCode, it does go up to 4.1 so I know my computer is capable of it.

This is actually for a larger project; I did try importing my project into xcode, merging it with Tom Dalling's project, it just won't work, I always get GL 2.1.

I'm compiling the above code with

```
g++ main.cpp -o GLTEST -lglfw -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo \
```

... maybe I'm missing an option. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: FWIW `glew` caused me nothing but problems on OS X. I removed it and everything was fine. Well I had to import `<OpenGL/OpenGL.h>` and `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` and *then* it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading about window creation hints [at the glfw site](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/window.html#window_hints), you'll find:

> These hints are set to their default values each time the library is initialized with glfwInit

and Tom Dalling's (working) code calls `glfwInit` before hinting about the version while yours does it afterwards.

So I suspect that may have something to do with it.